# Crontab starting gunicorn installed with pip, command not found

Tags: python, cron

I want to start a django application in gunicorn at reboot.

*All commands below are run as user simernes*

I have installed gunicorn with pip3:

```
pip3 install gunicorn
```

**crontab:**

```
crontab -e

@reboot /home/simernes/run_gunicorn.sh > /home/simernes/logfile 2>&1 &
```

**run_gunicorn.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/simernes/.bashrc
cd /home/simernes/djangoapp
gunicorn --bind localhost:8000 config.wsgi
```

However, when I go and reboot and check the log file it says:
line 4: gunicorn: command not found

Running the script on it's own from a ssh logged in terminal works fine.

Do I need to source the python environment for cron to be able to see the apps installed through pip, or something of the like?

Comment: Try `python3 gunicorn ...`

Comment: Sorry, @stovfl I should have specified that running gunicorn works fine in a normal terminal. It's just that the cron shell doesn't seem to have loaded the path where the gunicorn executable is

Comment: If your gunicorn is within a virtualenv you might have to enable it before running the unicorn

Comment: ***"works fine in a normal terminal"***: I assumed this, try it to just see if the Python interpreter can be found. ***"at reboot"***: Wy do you use `cron`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cron` runs your script in a shell with minimal environment variables and path, usually the following:

```
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=username>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=username>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/username>
```

Which means `gunicorn` or anything else not in `/usr/bin:/bin` wont be available to your script.

What you can do is export the path to `gunicorn` as an environment variable by adding something like this to your `crontab`:

`@reboot export GUNICORN=/path/to/gunicorn && /home/simernes/run_gunicorn.sh > /home/simernes/logfile 2>&1 &`

And in your script you execute `gunicorn` thusly:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/simernes/.bashrc
cd /home/simernes/djangoapp
$GUNICORN --bind localhost:8000 config.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give full path to `gunicorn` in the script